# How can there be zero ways of winning?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I was asked to find the ways of winning noughts and crosses in a $3\times3\times3$ cube. I worked it out. Then I was asked to work out $4\times4\times4$. Following that, I was asked to derive a formula that would work for any number of boxes on the cube (i.e $n^3$). I worked this out to be $3n^2 + 6n + 4$ = number of winning ways. This worked, however I noticed that with no cube when $n = 0$, there is still $4$ ways to win.

Can someone please help me conceptualize this.

If my explanation of the problem is not good enough for you to understand go to this link:

http://nrich.maths.org/895

Comment: Can you tell us how you figured that formula?

Comment: It would appear that your deduction of your formula is incorrect

Comment: What assumptions did you make in deriving that formula? I notice that it also fails for $n=1$.

Comment: It's easier to conceptualize what goes wrong in the $n=1$ case first.

Comment: I'm assuming it fails for n < 2 because the vetices are no longer unique and you are double counting.

Comment: Like @fleabood pointed out, this `James method' (as in the webpage) doesn't work for $n \leq 2$. If you feel that $n=1$ is silly, then the failure at $n=2$ surely demonstrates this.

Comment: I didn't bother to figure out which method this was or to verify whether the formula works.  However, its pretty clear which ever method is used a basic assumption that there are distinct space; the eight vertices are distinct-- of the six faces  adjacent faces will share an edge but no more,-- that a face will consist of more than one rows with distinct facess etc.  So if n=1 then these are vastly overcounted

Comment: ... or more egregious.  If you count the number of  lines that are vertical and add the number of lines that are horizontal (under the assumption a line may not be both) and the number of diagonal lines.  When if n= 1 the one line is all of those.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin why doesn't james method work for n=2?  That would be 28.  Which is correct I think.  4 vertical, 4 left-right, 4 front back, two diagonals for each face, and 4 verex to opposite vertex.

Comment: @fleablood oh you are right, James' method is correct at $n = 2$, ha I counted wrong and what is `surely demonstrated' was my poor judgement.

Comment: I first overcounted (badly) for n=2 and got 40.  (I figure there were 2 rows and 2 columns and 2 diagonals on each face, and 4 vertex to opposite vertex).  I saw the formula didn't agree with me but the formula gave a *smaller* answer and if it had an error it had to be overcounting so I figure *I* must have been over counting...

Answer (score 0):

I figure there are three dimensions.

In each dimension there are $n$ slices of the cube.  And in each slice there are $n$ distinct lines that traverse only in that one dimension. (e.g.  in a 4x4 cube there are four wall slices and each slice has 4 rows.)  So there are $n^2$ lines in that dimensions. Asumming lines traversing one dimension only are distinct from lines traversing the other dimensions this accounts for $3n^2$ lines.

But this assumption *fails* for $n = 1$.  In $n=1$ the one winning line is vertical while simultaneously being horizontal, and front to back.  I have triple counted.  For $n=0$ there is trivially no problem yet as $3*0^2 =0$.

Diagonal lines traverse in two dimensions.  In each dimensional slice there are two diagonal lines in each slice.  If $n > 1$ we can safely assume these lines are distinct from the previously counted lines that only traverse in one dimension.  These account for $3*(2n)$ more lines.

Again, the fails miserably for $n = 1$.  The one line is all of horizontal, veritical, front-to-back, diagonal in all 6 possible ways.  We have nonagonally over-counted.  We've counted 9 lines where there is only 1.  For $n=0$ we trivially haven't had a problem yet.

The last type of line are those that traverse in all 3 dimensions. These go from vertex to opposite vertex. As a cube has 8 vertices that are $4$ such lines.

Which obviously fails for $n=1$ as there is only one vertex that is its own opposite and the one line is the same one we have already counted 9 times.  So we have overcounted a whopping 13 times.  As for $n = 0$, there are clearly no vertices so this is overcounting by $4$.

So.. number of ways to win:  If $n \ge 2;$ $3n^2 + 6n + 4$, for $n=1; 2$ for $n=0; 0$.